# Unknown header type 4

Tags: usb-installation

When I boot up live or installation of Linux Ubuntu, before it goes to start page (loading of Ubuntu); it shows me a black screen with a text:

```
PCI 0000:01:02.0: Unknown header type 04, ignoring device...
```

What this text mean and can I safely install Linux - if not how to fix this issue

Comment: This is not a problem. If you have a real problem, you are welcome to ask.

Answer (score -2):

I recently had a similar problem.

Try taking out all PCI devices, checking for dust, and putting them back in. Maybe something isn't making a good connection because it's come loose or is dusty.